# Why does Intel XDK not start?

Tags: android, intel, intel-xdk, construct

After installing Intel XDK as a means to export my created Construct 2 game (CAPX) to Crosswalk for Android (APK), it seemed that it won't even open.

This is the error message I get:

[image: Intel XDK error message]

> The Intel XDK cannot run with your system configuration.
>
> Your system's HTTP proxy seems to be configured to manage localhost traffic. We tested http://172.0.0.1:58889 and found that is was being proxied. The Intel XDK requres a direct connection to its local server. Please add an exception to your proxy settings to allow traffic in 127.0.0.1 port 80 and also for 127.0.0.1 port 58889 and above depending on the number of devices you are using (2 port per device).

Comment: Thank you for improving the question Chris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is already telling you what the problem is: Your system is configured to redirect all traffic to your local machine to a proxy server.

Proxy servers are servers that are used to forward network traffic. They are often used in corporate networks and the like to allow filtering of traffic. Obviously your machine is also configured to send all the outgoing traffic to a proxy server.

When this is the case, the machine can not access itself without going through the proxy server. However, Intel XDK needs this connection not to go through the proxy server so you need to change your system configuration. The error message tells you how you can do this, see the last paragraph.

Comment: Hi Chris, I have tried the "or use a proxy server and check Bypass proxy server for local addresses" https://www.dropbox.com/s/60vaktl9dpq0zr0/2-ProxySetting.JPG?dl=0 and yes I am able to properly open the Intel XDK now. But another problem occurred: After using Intel XDK to generate the APK, the APK won't open. This is the error: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ypctwdkl49tirq4/x86error.png?dl=0 .

Comment: @GenesisEmmanuelGonzales If you have a new problem, please open a new question. If this answer has helped you, you can mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.